# not able to assign address to a public property using web3

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, remix

while everything is working fine when working on remix ide but on truffle its not updaing value of a property (player2)

i am also returning that address value and its returning as it should be. but not updating in contract;

### app.js

```
joinGame: function() {
    App.contracts.TicTacToe.deployed().then(function(instance) { 
        instance.joinGame.call()
        .then(function(res) { 
          console.log(res);
          $('#joinBtn').hide();
        });
    });
  },
```

### tictactoe.sol

```
function joinGame() public payable returns(address) {
     //require(msg.value > 0, 'value should be more than 0');
        require(msg.sender != player1, 'both player cant be same');
        player2 = msg.sender;
        player2Escrow = 100; // need to update this with msg.value;
        return player2;
    }
```

although i am returning address from which i am calling as player2 (only when calling join function) but stil while fetching player2 value is 0x0

pls help.

Comment: You're using a call, which can't make any state changes. You need to use a transaction. Note that transactions don't have return values.

Comment: changed still nothing happend `code` joinGame: function() {
    App.contracts.TicTacToe.deployed().then(function(instance) { 
        instance.joinGame.call({ from : web3.eth.accounts[1], })
        .then(function(res) {
          web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from : web3.eth.accounts[1],
            nonce : 0 
          }, function(err, transactionHash) {
              if (err) { 
                  console.log(err); 
              } else {
                  console.log(transactionHash);
              }
          });
          
        });
    });
  }, `code`

Comment: You're still doing a call: `instance.joinGame.call`. If you're using Truffle, this page might help: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts. (See also https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/truffle-contract#making-a-transaction-via-a-contract-function.) Otherwise please tell us what library you're using.

Comment: i am using below function for that and its working but calling two times, dnt know why....instance.performMove(xpos, ypos, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0]})
        .then(function(res) { 
          web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from : web3.eth.accounts[0],
            gas : 21000,
            value : 100
          }, function(err, transactionHash) {
              if (err) { 
                  console.log(err); 
              } else {
                  console.log(transactionHash);
              }
          });
        });

Comment: That code sends two transactions: one to call `performMove` and one for `web3.eth.sendTransaction`, which attempts to transfer 100 wei and will invoke the contract's fallback function.